# The command "git config remote.origin.url "${_old_remote%.git}"" failed and exited with 255 during

Tags: git, go, intellij-idea, travis-ci, ubuntu-16.04

Even though it compiles and runs perfectly in my machine, has no problems uploading it to github, when I try to use travis-CI (for the first time) shows the following error:
(I only have 2 external dependecies gorilla/mux and gorilla/context, which I obtained from "go get")

```
$ export GOPATH=$HOME/gopath
$ export PATH=$HOME/gopath/bin:$PATH
$ mkdir -p $HOME/gopath/src/["github.com/gorilla/mux", "github.com/gorilla/context"]
$ rsync -az ${TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR}/ $HOME/gopath/src/["github.com/gorilla/mux", "github.com/gorilla/context"]/
$ export TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR=$HOME/gopath/src/["github.com/gorilla/mux", "github.com/gorilla/context"]
/home/travis/build.sh: line 62: export: `github.com/gorilla/context]': not a valid identifier
$ cd $HOME/gopath/src/["github.com/gorilla/mux", "github.com/gorilla/context"]
error: could not lock config file .git/config: No such file or directory
The command "git config remote.origin.url "${_old_remote%.git}"" failed and exited with 255 during .
Your build has been stopped.
```

.travis.yml:

```
language: go
go:
  - 1.6.x
go_import_path:
  - github.com/gorilla/mux
  - github.com/gorilla/context
install:
  - github.com/gorilla/mux
  - github.com/gorilla/context
script:
  - go test -v ./...
```

I modified the .travis.yml file several times and I have no idea what is wrong/missing.

I have the default config file at ProjectName/.git/config

I also have the GO recommended directory set up GOPATH/src/github.com/User/ProjectName/

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Those aren't commands under your "install:" step, and `go_import_path` is supposed to be a path. See the docs: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build#Customizing-the-Installation-Step and https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/go/#Go-Import-Path You should also probably use an up to date version of Go.

Comment: @JimB, you are right, changed the install lines to "go get github.com/gorilla/..." and worked!